# Mixture models - am I on the right path?

Tags: probability, gaussian-mixture-distribution, chemometrics, multivariate-distribution

We have 2 chemical parameters measured for material 1 and 2. We are interested in finding out the probability of an unknown sample being the mixture of the two reference materials.
Also determination of the mixing ratio would be nice too.
Is this what is called mixture probabilities and mixture models?
Would it be possible to determine the mixing ratio of e.g. 3 or more reference materials? Or would we need more measurement parameters?